# How to concat two columns into map in hive

Tags: apache-spark, hive

I have a hive table

```
row1 (Id_1, locale_1, value_1)
row2 (Id_1, locale_2, value_2)
row3 (Id_1, locale_3, value_3)
row4 (Id_2, locale_1, value_1)
row5 (Id_2, locale_3, value_3)
```

How to make it like a map with primary key id?

```
row  (Id, Map<locale, value>)
```

like

```
row1  (Id_1, {locale_1 -> value_1, locale_2 -> value_2, locale_3 -> value_3})
row2  (Id_2, {locale_1 -> value_1, locale_3 -> value_3})
```

Thank you!

Comment: you should say what is the error you are getting instead of just asking how it can be done.

Answer (score 0):

If you are not worried about the order of key value pairs in your map coulmns, here is a quick way using map function in Spark DataFrame API

```
val data = Seq(
("Id_1", "locale_1", "value_1"),
 ("Id_1", "locale_2", "value_2"),
 ("Id_1", "locale_3", "value_3"),
 ("Id_2", "locale_1", "value_1"),
 ("Id_2", "locale_3", "value_3")
)
import spark.implicits._
val df = data.toDF("id", "locale", "value")

import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
val df2 = df.withColumn("myMap", map($"locale", $"value")).drop("locale").drop("value")

val df3 = df2
  .withColumn("myMap", map_entries(col("myMap")))
  .groupBy("id")
  .agg(map_from_entries(flatten(collect_set("myMap"))).as("myMap"))
```

Output of `df3.show(false)` will be
[image: output]